# How to use functions that are beyond your PHP version?

Tags: php, linux, apache, mod-rewrite

I use shared hosting with Hostgator. My version of php is 5.2.17 and that does not include **mod_rewrite**. Is there any way that I could link to or use mod_rewrite anyway? Here is some more info:

**Why do you need mod_rewrite?**
I want to try out an open source classifieds system called '[Open Source Classifieds](http://open-classifieds.com/)' and mod_rewrite is one of the install dependencies. (*incidentally the only dependency that I am missing*). BTW if you know of any alternative opensoure classifieds systems out there that I could use instead, do tell.

**Why don't you just upgrade php?**
Well, because I can't. I have shared hosting and tech support confirmed that this is not possible. One option  would be to upgrade to dedicated hosting which costs a lot more than I am willing to pay just yet..

Comment: mod_rewrite is part of Apache, so if it isn't loaded then you won't be able to use it

Comment: It doesn't depend on your PHP version either, in particular not to minor and patch numbers.

Comment: Switch to a better host.

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled on shared accounts on hostgator, are you sure your asking the right question?

Comment: https://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/hardware-software/apache-modules-that-are-on-all-of-our-shared-servers its 2nd from bottom "mod_rewrite.c" + read the "Article Comments"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP never contains `mod_rewrite` as it is part of Apache (the [Apache Webserver](http://httpd.apache.org/) to be more correct).

So instead of verifying PHP for it, contact support of your hoster and ask if you have got `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` available for your hosting plan.

Answer (score 0):

Only the web server administrator can install and enable mod_rewrite.

Either you manage to convince the tech support to do it for you, or you find another software that doesn't need to use mode_rewrite.